# Counting distinct values with side condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a table named `tableName` in excel like this:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
 1111    aaaa
 1111    bbbb
 1111    aaaa
 1111    cccc
 1111    aaaa
 1111    aaaa
 1111    aaaa
 2222    aaaa
 2222    aaaa
 2222    ffff
 2222    aaaa
 2222    aaaa
 3333    bbbb
 3333    bbbb
 4444    aaaa
 4444    bbbb
```

I already got this (in cell `B2`):

```
{=SUM(IF((tableName[ColumnB]=B$1)*1;1/COUNTIFS(tableName[ColumnA];tableName[ColumnA];tableName[ColumnB];B$1)))}
```

with `aaaa` in cell `B1` for counting the distinct values in `ColumnA` where `ColumnB` contains `aaaa`. Here the result is 3 (1111 and 2222 and 4444), the marked columns are counted:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
 1111    aaaa      <----is counted lets call it 1
 1111    bbbb      <--------not counted because ColumnB isn't aaaa
 1111    aaaa      <----not counted because duplicate of 1
 1111    cccc      <--------not counted because ColumnB isn't aaaa
 1111    aaaa      <----not counted because duplicate of 1
 1111    aaaa      <----not counted because duplicate of 1
 1111    aaaa      <----not counted because duplicate of 1
 2222    aaaa      <----is counted lets call it 2
 2222    aaaa      <----not counted because duplicate of 2
 2222    ffff      <--------not counted because ColumnB isn't aaaa
 2222    aaaa      <----not counted because duplicate of 2
 2222    aaaa      <----not counted because duplicate of 2
 3333    bbbb      <--------not counted because ColumnB isn't aaaa
 3333    bbbb      <--------not counted because ColumnB isn't aaaa
 4444    aaaa      <----is counted lets call it 3
 4444    bbbb      <--------not counted because ColumnB isn't aaaa
```

Now I have got `bbbb` in cell `A2` and want to want to count the same, but there must be an other row with the same value in `ColumnA` and `A2`(=bbbb) in `ColumnB`.

```
ColumnA ColumnB
 1111    aaaa      <----is counted because x exists
 1111    bbbb      <--------this is x
 1111    aaaa
 1111    cccc
 1111    aaaa
 1111    aaaa
 1111    aaaa
 2222    aaaa      <----not counted because no pair (2222, bbbb) exists
 2222    aaaa
 2222    ffff
 2222    aaaa
 2222    aaaa
 3333    bbbb
 3333    bbbb
 4444    aaaa      <----is counted because y exists
 4444    bbbb      <--------this is y
```

I don't know how to do this.

---

My complete aim is to create a contingency table like:

```
     aaaa bbbb cccc ffff
aaaa  3    2    1    1    
bbbb  2    3    1    0
cccc  1    1    1    0
ffff  1    0    0    1
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement. Please rephrase, possibly with an example.

Comment: Confused by *'Now I have got bbbb in cell A2 and want to want to count the same, but there must be an other column with the same value in ColumnA and A2(=bbbb) in ColumnB.'*; see [mcve]

Comment: @Jeeped sorry, corrected "column" in "row" (and added more examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TableName[ColumnB]=B1)*  
  (0<COUNTIFS(TableName[ColumnA],TableName[ColumnA],TableName[ColumnB],A2))
/COUNTIFS(TableName[ColumnA],TableName[ColumnA],TableName[ColumnB],TableName[ColumnB]))
```

p.s. it's not a *CSE* formula, no need for Ctrl+Shift+Enter though it will work as well.

[image]

Comment: One Note to @Ben: to make it draggable all the `TableName[ColumnB]` will need to be `tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]]` same with column A.  Also make sure the `B1` is `B$1` and the `A2` is `$A2`

Comment: @ScottCraner Am I right, that it already is vertical draggable? Or am I loosing cells by dragging vertical? And `tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]]` and also `tablename[[ColumnA]:[ColumnA]]` (both needed) make it horizontal draggable?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks.
(at) A.S.H. (and ScottCraner) I make it horizontally draggable by using it as a CSE formula ;)

Comment: @Ben no the CSE is still not needed: Put this in the first and drag over and down. `=SUMPRODUCT((tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]]=B$1)*
  (0<COUNTIFS(tablename[[ColumnA]:[ColumnA]],tablename[[ColumnA]:[ColumnA]],tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]],$A2))
/COUNTIFS(tablename[[ColumnA]:[ColumnA]],tablename[[ColumnA]:[ColumnA]],tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]],tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]]))`

Comment: Yes, I understood that from your comment before. My old solution was to use CSE (than you don't need the `tablename[[ColumnB]:[ColumnB]`-syntax. It was only FYI why I use CSE in my question)

Comment: Is there a way to move the `ColumnB` out of the formula and only write `tablename[[X1]:[X1]]` with `ColumnB` in cell `X1`